# MVC - jQuery - DataTables pass array to datatable.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc, datatable

Just need a second set of eye with me, I am working with MVC jQuery and DataTables I have 5 textboxes and one button, on click I run a script that adds the data to an object array like this:

```
var productarray = new Array();

function addproduct() {
  if ($("#ReqQuant").val() == null) {
    alert("Please add product quantity")
  } else if ($("#productprice").val() == null) {
    alert("PLease select product")
  } else {
    var productname = $("#productname").val();
    var productprice = $("#productprice").val();
    var productquantity = $("#ReqQuant").val();
    var producttotalprice = $("#OrderDetailProductTotalPricetxt").val();
    var producttax = $("#OrderDetailProductTaxTXT").val();
    calculatesubtotal(producttotalprice);
    productarray.push({
      A_productname: productname,
      A_productprice: productprice,
      A_productquantity: productquantity,
      A_producttotalprice: producttotalprice,
      A_producttax: producttax
    });
    var arrayjson = JSON.stringify(productarray);
    $('#RetailQouteTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
  }
```

Then I have a table already configured in the HTMl section like this:

```
<table id="RetailQouteTable">
  <tr>
    @*
    <th>Product #</th>*@
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Required Quantity</th>
    <th>Unit Price</th>
    <th>Total Price</th>
    <th>Tax</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The next step is configuring the datatable in the script section like this:

```
$('#RetailQouteTable').DataTable({                       
  "data": "arrayjson",
  "columns":
  [
    {"data":"A_productname", title: "Product Name"},  
    {"data": "A_productquantity", title: "Required Quantity"},
    {"data": "A_productprice", title: "Unit Price"},
    {"data": "A_producttotalprice", title: "Total Price"},
    {"data": "A_producttax", title: "Tax"} 
  ]
});
```

So, when I click the add button, the data is inserted in the array then I receive this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=RetailQouteTable - Invalid JSON response.

also I want to add the format of the "arrayjson" looks something like this

```
"[{\"A_productname\":\"2\",\"A_productprice\":\"2.50\",\"A_productquantity\":\"10\",\"A_producttotalprice\":\"25\",\"A_producttax\":\"3.25\"},{\"A_productname\":\"3\",\"A_productprice\":\"4.90\",\"A_productquantity\":\"20\",\"A_producttotalprice\":\"98\",\"A_producttax\":\"12.74\"}]"
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: Since you're not include controller action method contents, check the response in browser's dev console. If it's not JSON, possibly you should remove double quotes in `"arrayjson"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line: $('#RetailQouteTable').DataTable().ajax.reload(); has caused the error. Also try to remove the double quote of "arrayjson".

Comment: syntax wise that's not correct, but anyways I tried it didn't go through.

Comment: Also, you want to add data directly in the DataTable which for me doesn't make sense because these data will be removed when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old but it might b helpful.

There are multiple mistakes in the above code :

**1)** Always use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tag while working with *DataTables.js*

Edit your *HTML* table to below :

```
<table id="RetailQouteTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      @*
      <th>Product #</th>*@
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Required Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Total Price</th>
      <th>Tax</th>
    </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
  .
  .
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**2)** Change your *DataTable* call to below :

```
$('#RetailQouteTable').DataTable({                       
  data: arrayjson,
  columns:
  [
    {title: "Product Name"},  
    {title: "Required Quantity"},
    {title: "Unit Price"},
    {title: "Total Price"},
    {title: "Tax"} 
  ]
});
```

Using inverted commas around `arrayjson` might consider it as a string, which is incorrect.

To avoid any inconvenience, use the below data format. i.e. Array of Arrays, e.g.

```
var arrayjson = [
    [ "2", "2.50", "10", "25", "3.25"],
    [ "3", "4.90", "20", "98", "12.74" ]
];
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/512n4z8t/7/) is the working example.

Hope this helps.